# Spring bootRun fails during the installation of a plateform

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, neo4j

I want to install an online framework locally. I downloaded the code source and then followed the steps described on this [link](https://gitlab.com/TIBHannover/orkg/orkg-backend). However, when I give this command **"./gradlew bootRun"** to run the spring boot, I am receiving these errors: **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"**

```
> Task :bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
```

I've tried to install **Neo4J** and **postgresql** but it doesn't resolve the problem.
I am using **ubuntu 20.14** as OS.

After trying other suggestions posted here, I used these two commands:

```
./gradlew clean 
./gradlew build
```

But the build is failed and I am getting this error:

```
   Resource Controller > excludeByClass() FAILED
        java.lang.AssertionError at ResourceControllerTest.kt:221

 Task :integrationTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':integrationTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/anouar/Downloads/orkg-backend-master/build/reports/tests/integrationTest/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 59s
```

**UPDATE:**
After etablishing the connection to the PostgreSQL server, the execution is freezing in 80% as shown in this screenshot:
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NodeJs** is not required, forget it. Ok, you mean Neo4J

> bootRun task that allows a developer to start the application in a
> “developer mode” without first building a JAR file and then starting
> this JAR file allows you to run the application **bypassing the test**.

./gradlew build only build your project/software. It does not execute it.
**./gradlew bootRun** can be used to quickly compile and run your application

During build, other phases are executed, like test phase. If you want to compile the project by passing the tests, run

```
./gradlew build -x test
```

For the purpose you have (to run the application), it is not necessary to run the tests at this time.

You must make sure you have postgres installed.
You must make sure exists a database user named "postgres" as **required by your application**. https://gitlab.com/TIBHannover/orkg/orkg-backend/-/blob/master/src/main/resources/config/application.yml#L35

Your application tries to connect to the PostgreSQL server using a user named "postgres" with password "postgres".

Fails, when not finding connection with the server or the attempt to connect with the user "postgres" fails.

You can look at this article or some other related
https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-set-the-default-user-password-in-postgresql/

**UPDATE:**

**Error:**
scheme 'none' is only allowed when authentication is disabled

> As with any other Spring Boot starter, the only thing you have to do
> is to include the starter module via your dependency management.  If
> you don’t configure anything, than the starter assumes
> bolt://localhost:7687 as Neo4j URI and a server that has **disabled**
> **authentication**. https://neo4j.com/developer/java-driver-spring-boot-starter/

By default your application doesn't provide user/password.
Add username/password to your yaml configuration:  https://gitlab.com/TIBHannover/orkg/orkg-backend/-/blob/master/src/main/resources/config/application.yml#L31

```
  data:
    neo4j:
      uri: bolt://localhost:7687
      username: admin
      password: admin
```

**How to test your Neo4J password**

Make sure that you can navigate http://localhost:7474/ you will be redirected to http://localhost:7474/browser/
Provide user/password
admin
admin

Then you will see the neo4J Dashboard

**UPDATE 2**

Try this>  **If you didn't provide the no auth option on startup**, the default username and password is neo4j/neo4j." You need to select "Username/password Authentication type" and provide your user/password.

Note:I have changed my user / password to exemplify in the image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for the mistake, yes it is neo4j not nodejs. Your solution fixes partially my issue. You have right, the problem was the connection to the PostgreSQL server, and after etablishing the connection, the execution is freezing in 80%, and the localhost:8080 doesn't work. I don't know if I have to wait or there is a problem? Please see the update of question

Comment: Can you provide the relevant log lines?

For example:
  Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: etc.
or
  Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:7687 etc.
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I made a screenshot in the update, please check it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I tried to follow your instructions, so what I need to do is to configure my Neo4j, so I edit my "application.yml" and when I tried to connect using the given username/password, I got this error: "Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure."

Comment: According to the new error you mention.
I firmly believe that you only need to specify the correct user password.

In my case, my user/password is admin/admin.

Provide your own user/password.

This might help:

"Let's hop into their nice portal that Neo4j provides. Open http://localhost:7474 in a browser. When asked to authenticate just choose the drop down "no authentication." If you didn't provide the no auth option on startup, the default username and password is neo4j/neo4j." https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-databases/neo4j-browser

Comment: Sorry Juan again for the late answer due to the time zone difference. The "no auth" didn't resolve the problem, I am getting an error, please see the screenshot oh the new update, I think I have to create a databse before the etablishment of connection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227493/discussion-between-anouar-and-juan-carlos-alafita).